Execute code after modal popup fully loaded in angular
I'm using ngx-bootstrap/modal
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService, ModalOptions } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
   
constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}
    
this.modalService.show(this.Content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title', keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static', }).result.then((result: LinkDetail) => {

Here i'm getting

Property 'result' does not exist on type 'BsModalRef'

any solution to fix this issue because i want to execute some lines of code after modal is fully loaded
thanks

I think the open is synchronous and there is no need to wait for any promise. I checked the source code for show method.
You can simply put the logic inside a setTimeout, which will happen after the modal opens.
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService, ModalOptions } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
   
constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}
    
this.modalService.show(this.Content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title', keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static', });

setTimeout(() => {
    // write your logic here!
});


I believe is this is what you are looking for. You could use (onShown) hook to do something in your code.
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/modals?tab=overview#service-events
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/modals?tab=overview#directive-events
